Booking Mobile App cant show time on schedule as button grey


import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  BORDERRADIUS,
  COLORS,
  FONTFAMILY,
  FONTSIZE,
  SPACING,
} from '../theme/theme';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import ScheduleCard from '../components/ScheduleCard';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
import CustomIcon from '../components/CustomIcon';

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const ScheduleScreen = () => {
  const [fieldData, setFieldData] = useState([]);

  const fetchFieldData = async () => {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection('lapangan')
        .orderBy('created_at')
        .get();
      const data: any = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const document = doc.data();
        document.id_lapangan = doc.id;
        document.image = document.image ? document.image : '';
        return document;
      });
      setFieldData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching field data:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFieldData();
  }, []);

  const [date, setDate] = useState(moment().tz('Asia/Singapore').toDate());
  const [showDatePicker, setShowDatePicker] = useState(false);
  const [bookingData, setBookingData] = useState([]);
  const availableTimes = [
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0),
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0),
  ];

  const handleDateChange = (event: any, selectedDate: any) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShowDatePicker(false);

    const selectedDateTime = moment(currentDate).tz('Asia/Singapore');
    const selectedDateOnly = selectedDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    const today = moment().tz('Asia/Singapore');
    const normalizedCurrentDate = moment(selectedDateOnly).startOf('day');
    const normalizedToday = moment(today).tz('Asia/Singapore').startOf('day');

    if (normalizedCurrentDate.isBefore(normalizedToday)) {
      Alert.alert('Tanggal tidak valid', 'Tolong pilih tanggal yang valid');
      return;
    }

    setDate(selectedDateTime.toDate());
  };

  const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState(null);
  const [selectedFieldId, setSelectedFieldId] = useState(null);
  const handleImageClick = async (selectedFieldId: any) => {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection('booking')
        .where('id_lapangan', '==', selectedFieldId?.id_lapangan)
        .get();

      const bookings: any = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

      setBookingData(bookings);
      setSelectedTime(null);

      console.log('Data booking :', bookings);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching booking data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <FlatList
          data={fieldData}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal
          contentContainerStyle={styles.containerGap}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <ScheduleCard
              shouldMarginatedAtEnd={true}
              onPress={() => handleImageClick(item.id_lapangan)}
              cardWidth={windowWidth / 2}
              isFirst={index == 0 ? true : false}
              isLast={index === fieldData.length - 1}
              title={item.nama_lapangan}
              floor={item.lantai_lapangan}
              imagePath={item.image}
            />
          )}
        />
        <View style={styles.containerX}>
          <Text style={styles.dateInfoText}>Pilih Tanggal</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.touchableInputX}
            onPress={() => setShowDatePicker(true)}>
            <Text style={styles.touchableInputTextX}>
              {moment(date)
                .tz('Asia/Singapore')
                .locale('id')
                .format('dddd, DD MMMM YYYY')}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {showDatePicker && (
            <DateTimePicker
              value={moment(date).tz('Asia/Singapore').toDate()}
              mode="date"
              locale="id-ID"
              display="spinner"
              onChange={handleDateChange}
            />
          )}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {Array.from(Array(4), (_, row) => (
            <View style={styles.row} key={`row_${row}`}>
              {Array.from(Array(row === 0 || row === 3 ? 3 : 4), (_, col) => {
                let index;
                if (row === 0) {
                  index = col;
                } else if (row === 1) {
                  index = 3 + col;
                } else if (row === 2) {
                  index = 7 + col;
                } else if (row === 3) {
                  index = 11 + col;
                }
                if (index < availableTimes.length) {
                  const time = availableTimes[index];
                  const isTimeBooked = bookingData.find(
                    booking =>
                      moment(booking.waktu).isSame(date) &&
                      moment(booking.waktu).hours() === time.getHours(),
                  );

                  return (
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                      key={`button_${index}`}
                      onPress={() => setSelectedTime(time)}>
                      <View
                        style={[
                          styles.button,
                          isTimeBooked ? styles.buttonUnavailable : null, // Menambahkan kondisi untuk tampilan tombol yang sudah dipesan
                        ]}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                          {time.getHours()}:00
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                  );
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              })}
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.timeRadioContainer}>
          <View style={styles.radioContainer}>
            <CustomIcon
              name="radio"
              style={[styles.radioIcon, {color: COLORS.Orange}]}
            />
            <Text style={styles.radioText}>Tersedia</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.radioContainer}>
            <CustomIcon
              name="radio"
              style={[styles.radioIcon, {color: COLORS.Grey}]}
            />
            <Text style={styles.radioText}>Tidak Tersedia</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: COLORS.Black,
  },
  containerX: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    marginVertical: SPACING.space_16,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: SPACING.space_4,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  wrapper: {
    marginVertical: SPACING.space_32,
  },
  touchableInputX: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: COLORS.White,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.Orange,
    borderRadius: BORDERRADIUS.radius_10,
    marginHorizontal: 40,
    paddingVertical: SPACING.space_10,
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  touchableInputTextX: {
    fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.poppins_semibold,
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_16,
    color: COLORS.White,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  textHeader: {
    fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.poppins_semibold,
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_14,
    color: COLORS.White,
    paddingHorizontal: SPACING.space_36,
    paddingVertical: SPACING.space_32,
  },
  dateInfoText: {
    fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.poppins_regular,
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_14,
    color: COLORS.White,
    marginBottom: SPACING.space_4,
    marginLeft: SPACING.space_28,
  },
  containerGap: {
    gap: SPACING.space_36,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  button: {
    width: windowWidth * 0.18,
    height: 30,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: BORDERRADIUS.radius_10,
    borderColor: COLORS.White,
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.Orange,
  },
  buttonUnavailable: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.Grey,
  },
  buttonSelected: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.White,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.poppins_semibold,
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_14,
    color: COLORS.White,
  },
  timeRadioContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: SPACING.space_4,
    marginBottom: SPACING.space_10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
  radioContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    gap: SPACING.space_10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  radioIcon: {
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_20,
    color: COLORS.White,
  },
  radioText: {
    fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.poppins_medium,
    fontSize: FONTSIZE.size_12,
    color: COLORS.White,
  },
});

export default ScheduleScreen;

i have 2 collection lapangan and booking
so after i clicked an image it get data id_lapangan from booking while id_lapangan data is lapangan document id.
my point is after i fetch data frm booking collection, choosing a date and the time on my app it didn't change the touchablewithoutfeedback bgcolor from orange to grey.
how to make it right thank you.

The variable, the one deciding what button you see is a const. Make the isTimeBooked a state variable and it will change as expected. On phone so can't give an example now. Let me know if you need one and I will spin one up in the morning.

still didn't change after changing it
